# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I've downloaded eclipse for ubuntu and I configure it with Tomcat 7 and I'm running eclipse with JDK 7.

When I start the server from the Servers tab, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Rule
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:426)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 7 more
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I think its happens becoz of Firewall problem,
Check the firewall settings.

Answer (score -1):

Just check whether you are trying to start Apache more than once i.e. through cmd and/or eclipse(some IDE)